# Passing two files containing data in different format to a mapper

Tags: hadoop

I have 5 image files (each image file less than 5MB).

```
ImageDir/Image1 = {ImageID1 <image in binary form>}
...
ImageDir/Image5 = {ImageID5 <image in binary form>}
```

There is some textual data that is also associated with the image,

```
ImageData/Image1_data = {ImageID1 <text data>}
...
ImageData/Image5_data = {ImageID5 <text data>}
```

I want each image and its text data to go to one mapper. How do I achieve this? I know that each image would go to one mapper but how to make sure that images text data which is in different form also goes to the same mapper.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easiest approach is to combine the image and associated data into a single file (gz, tar etc) using a script in an automated way and let a mapper process it.
2. AFAIK, Hadoop OOB doesn't support this. So, a [custom InputFormat](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat) needs to be coded. Won't recommend this approach as the image and the associated data might be on different nodes and there will be a lot of data shuffling during the job execution.

Comment: I think for first case where I pack image_file and associated data in a single tar file and either compress it or set isSplitable() to return false, I would have to write my own InputFormat and RecordReader?

Comment: Basically suppose I have .tar.gz file then (1) will MR automatically decompress this file and then give it to RecordReader. (2) Will RecordReader have to untar the file and then read each file contents and convert it into Key/Value pair. For data I may use key as ImageData and Value as Actual_Data and for Image I may use key as ImageContents and Value as Actual_Image_Contents. Then mapper would have to interpret these keys and associated values. Is this right? Is there any example of InputFormat/RecordReader that deals with .tar or .zip files. Will using Hadoop archive (.har) simplify the job?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum for learning things. Go through a couple of articles on Hadoop, if possible buy a book, try out Hadoop on a single node then on a cluster and then ask questions. `Would like to tell again than SO is not a forum for learning things`. Spends some effort and then ask questions.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question here. I am new to Hadoop and MapReduce, and am just confused as there are so many ways to do something in hadoop and am not sure what is the best method. I have purchased the hadoop book. And currently going thorough it. Meanwhile is there a forum where I can ask these questions and get quick access to code (as I am sure many people would have tried this and may have better insight into this) or is self-experimentation the best thing.